# PLC writing Software

Tags: microcontroller, plc

I wanted to create my own PLC and PLC supporting software.

I would like to know how to get started.

- Is there any software available to create background software?
- What is a recommended controller for such applications?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE but please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The other problem is that the question is too broad. I suggest that you edit this to one specific technical question you have about the project.

Comment: "*What is a recommended controller for such applications?*" What is your PLC going to do? Combinational logic, PID, motion, Ethernet comms, vision, ...? Your question has no specifications so it can't be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider implementing the [IEC 61131](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61131) standard. If I recall correctly there is open-source software to get you started.